# Bind event listener and keep element as this

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Let's say I have a function taking two arguments, like this:

```
function displaySum(a, b) {
    this.textContent = a + b;
}
```

I also have a button:

```html
<button id="my-button"></button>
```

I would like to make a `sum()` function my event listener, but passing `a` and `b` exclusively. I know it can be done this way:

```
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener(sum.bind(null, 3, 7));
```

The problem is that `this` is lost that way. I tried setting it to `null` or `undefined` and hope that it says *ignore this and let others inject their this*, but instead it sets `this` to `undefined` or `null` in strict mode and to `Window` in non-strict mode. Is it possible to keep the event target as `this` after binding?

Disclaimer: I'm asking for educational purpose, not looking for other ways to achieve the same result, as I know them.

Comment: Bind, call and apply are the only functions in JS that can modify context on functions. Is there a specific reason you want to use `this` inside the calculation function? Doesn't look like something I'd use in a real world application.

Comment: Obviously it’s not a real-world example, but I have needed to pass arguments to an event callback a few times in the past. I did it using an anonymous function as a wrapper back then. My inner perfectionist was curious if there is another way.

Comment: I see. I've wondered this a few times myself as well, but I came to the conclusion that a concise arrow function wrapper is the best practice for me. Separating the calculation logic from modifying the DOM is always a good idea anyways, adhering to the OOP philosophy, so it's probably for the best this way.

Comment: I prefer to use a non-arrow function in this case to be honest. Instead of injecting `event.target` manually, I prefer to use the value passed to `this` by the browser. I know they are equal, but anyway it's one of a few cases where I avoid arrow functions. I do love them in most of other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of approaches to this:

First, pass the target element as the first argument to `bind()`:

```
let el = document.getElementById('my-button');
el.addEventListener('click', sum.bind(el, 3, 7));
```

or

```
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', evt => sum.call(evt.target, 3, 7));
```

Second, use an anonymous function to retain scope:

```
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', function() { sum.call(this, 3, 7) });
```

Comment: Have you seen the disclaimer? I know these methods, just was curious if there is a way to ignore `this` parameter for `bind()`.

Comment: Then I don't understand what your interest is here. No, the `this` parameter can't be ignored. Not sure if you're asking if it can be made to have an inferred, default value.

Comment: I'm asking if I can bind parameters without binding `this`.

Comment: I guess no. I will accept your answer, as it gives nice workarounds. Just please correct two mistakes: 1. Missing `'click'`, 2. In second and third idea it should be `.call()` instead of `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use an assigner function declared beforehand to reduce hard coding, that way you don't need to explicitly pass anything. For example:

```
const missingText = event => event.target.innerText = 'Missing parameters';
```

If you want to assign dynamic value you can use a generator pattern as well:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

const setSum = (a, b) => (event) => event.target.innerText = sum(a, b);

document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', setSum(3, 7));
```

Might look a bit daunting if you're not familiar with the generator pattern, but in my opinion it's much cleaner, less and more readable code, and no binding required.

Comment: I can think of dozen of different ways to achieve the same effect, but that's not the point here. Hence the disclaimer.

Comment: I know, but since you said you have an inner perfectionist in you, I thought they might like this way since it's one of the most elegant I've yet come across.

Comment: It's not always possible though. When I said I needed to do it a few times in the past, it was always with some libraries. I wouldn't write a function myself like that if I knew I need to set the parameters in a callback.

Comment: My inner perfectionists also says that parentheses would be nice in an arrow function returning another one. So `a => (b => c)` instead of `a => b => c`.

Comment: Ah now I see. Well in that case you can use either binding, or a value setter function similar to setSum in my answer, only more universal.